# RecylerView showing only one element and blank spaces when it is inside NestedScrollView

Tags: java, android, xml

I want the toolbar and a linearLayout above the recyclerView to scroll when scrolling the items of recyclerView so i placed it in a nestedScrollView and set the recylerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false) but now i am getting only on element of the recyclerView and blank spaces instead of rest of the elements

```
                  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
            <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                tools:context=".MainActivity">
            
                <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
                    android:fillViewport="true"
                    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    >
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:paddingTop="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent">
                            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                                android:id="@+id/feed_toolbar"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                >
                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:id="@+id/feed_linear"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:orientation="horizontal">
            
                                    <LinearLayout
                                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_weight="1">
            
                                        <TextView
                                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                            android:fontFamily="@font/billabong"
                                            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                                            android:paddingTop="10dp"
                                            android:text="@string/instagram"
                                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                                            android:textSize="33dp" />
            
                                    </LinearLayout>
            
                                    <LinearLayout
                                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                                        android:layout_weight="1"
                                        android:gravity="end">
            
                                        <ImageView
                                            android:layout_width="30dp"
                                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                                            android:id="@+id/notification_custom"
                                            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                                            android:src="@drawable/heart_red" />
            
                                        <ImageView
                                            android:id="@+id/message_icon"
                                            android:layout_width="30dp"
                                            android:layout_height="30dp"
                                            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                                            android:src="@drawable/messenger" />
            
                                    </LinearLayout>
                                </LinearLayout>
                            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
                        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
            
                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/feed_story_linear"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="100dp"
                            android:background="@color/white"
                            android:orientation="horizontal" />
                        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                            android:id="@+id/feed_recyler"
                            android:clipToPadding="false"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            
                    </LinearLayout>
            
                </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
            
            
            
            </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: only one element* sorry for the typo

Comment: You can [edit] your question to fix the typo.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to adjust the layout height of **NestedScrollView** to match the parent and set a fixed size for **RecyclerView** to false.

```
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: tried it but nothing happened i am still getting only one element of the recylerView and blank spaces instead

Answer (score 0):

So what worked for me is Placing the linearLayout inside the appBarLayout and below the toolbar and using the scrollFlags ="scroll|enterAlways" and setting the layout_behaviour of recyclerView to @string/appbar_scrolling_view_behaviour

```
          <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".AnotherActivity">
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                                            >
                     <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                   app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                       android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     >

                        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
                      <LinearLayout
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="100dp"
                       android:background="#fff"
                                           >

                      </LinearLayout>
                  </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
                 <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:id="@+id/feed_recyler"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#FFF2"
                      
              app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
              >

          </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```